# Activate the global/default environment with new Pkg (Pkg3)

Tags: package, julia

In Julia 1.0's new `pkg` REPL mode, I can activate some package's or project's environment defined in the current directory as follows:

```
(v1.0) pkg> activate .

(ThePackage) pkg> # Now in ThePackage's environment
```

But how do I get back to the global `v1.0` environment, without having to restart the REPL, or finding and manually specifying the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `activate` without the argument:

```
(ThePackage) pkg> activate

(v1.0) pkg> # Back in global environment
```

Comment: Right, `activate` works kind of like `cd` in the terminal (no arguments bring you back to the home environment).